# Struts2 Grid plugin - remove select all checkbox

Tags: jquery, struts2, grid

I would like to use the following example:

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        caption="Customer Examples"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
        multiselect="true"
        multiboxonly="true"
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" formatter="currency" sortable="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>
```

The multiselect and multibox options show a checkbox on the left of the grid. The problem is that I only want the user be able to make one selection, and therefore do not need the "select all" checkbox that is added on the top.

Is there an option to do so? Or is there a way to extend JQuery grid tags to remove this button? I looked at the tag templates, and some source files but could not figure where to start (and if it is the right approach).

Comment: have you tried to make `multiselect="false"`?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 that's a good idea I didn't even though of. I tried it right now, but it removes all checkboxes.

Comment: OK, i understand you now. it removes you all the checkboxes, so you can click on the line to select. if you really wanna remove the checkbox, you can simply hide it using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following scripts:

```
$("input#cb_gridtable").hide(); // this hides the checkbox
```

ps: gridtable = id for your grid

Comment: Any idea on how to remove some checkboxes (based on the grid values), I tried a similar approach as what you describe but it fails because the grid is refreshed after my changes...